# AngularJs: Controllers calls service method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I tried to create a method in the services.js :

var esServices= angular.module('esServices', []);

```
esServices.factory('boxItems', ['$http', function($http) {
              ................
          }]); 

esServices.factory('cartItems', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
        array = $cookieStore.get('key');
        var cartItems = new function(){},           
        cartItems.addItem = function(itemSelected){     
        $cookieStore.put('key', []);        
    array.push(itemSelected);
   $cookieStore.put('key', array);   
                }
      }]);
```

in my controllers I call the service method:

```
         esControllers.controller('esList', ['$scope','cartItems','$cookieStore',
                    function($scope,cartItems,$cookieStore) {          
              cartItems.addItem($scope.element,function(){});
     };
  }]);

(itemSelected is an object)
```

Do you Know if it is possible to pass values (objects) from Controller to Service Method in this way?

Somebody can help me!!!

Comment: Can you post rest of the services.js?

Comment: You don't have a return statement in your service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
esServices.factory('cartItems', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
        return {
            addItem: function(itemSelected){
                var array = $cookieStore.get('key');       
                array.push(itemSelected);
                $cookieStore.put('key', array);
            },
            removeItem: function(){
                //...
            }
        }    
}]);
```

then call using

```
cartItems.addItem(itemSelected);
```

Comment: But I have the method addItem, removeItem and getItem

Comment: so then you add another function called removeItem in the same way, `addItem:function(){...}, removeItem: function(){...}`. you then call each of these methods in the controller using `cartItems.method()`. Angular services need a return statement and in this instance you're returning an object of functions

Comment: Before  var array = $cookieStore.get('key'); I tried to print itemSelected, this object is empty....maybe I wrong to obtain the object from controller...

Comment: Do you Know if it is possible to pass values (objects) from Controller to Service Method in this way?

Comment: you just pass it through the function parameters like you would any other function. so if you wanted to pass `$scope.object` from the controller to your `addItem()` function in the service you would call `cartItems.addItem($scope.object)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should inject the service in the controller like

```
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'] );
        app.factory('cartItems', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
          return {
             addItems : function(){
                alert('hello');   
             }  
          }
       }]);
       app.controller('MyController',function($scope,cartItems){
         $scope.test = 'my test';
         cartItems.addItems();
      });
```

If you want to use your ugly syntax :) just return **cartItems** from your factory